# Why can't my app load MvcApplication?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

I am having trouble running my asp.net mvc 2 app. using VS2010 ASP.NET Development Server.

error displayed in browser:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
 Parser Error
 Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 
 Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'PrototypeB.MvcApplication'.
 Source Error: 
  Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="PrototypeB.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>
 Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1 
 Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

global.aspx.cs:

```
namespace PrototypeB
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        ...
```

Comment: Can you check that it is compiled, and the dlls are in the appropriate bin directory.

Comment: let us see further information that appeared on your screen below this err

Comment: Are you deploying this to IIS 6? If so there are additional steps that need to be taken to get the pretty MVC urls to work. You can google this step. Also if you are deploying it to a server do you have MVC installed on the server? Or are you bin deploying the required MVC dlls?

Comment: @Yuriy yes PrototypeB.dll did build in my bin\Debug folder

Comment: @Frank I'm not deploying atm, just using the local ASP.NET Development Server

Comment: Can you try creating a new MVC project, compile it and then attempt to run it? See if you get a similar problem. Perhaps there is something going on with your namespace PrototypeB, is your default controller not in this namespace by chance? Is there a typo or other syntactic error one of your ASP directives at the top of your views? like this one in the global.asax? <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="PrototypeB.MvcApplication" Language="C#" %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please copy paste the namespace in Global.asax file, right click on Global.asax and choose  'View Markup' to see it

https://forums.asp.net/t/1559469.aspx/1?Could+not+load+type+MvcApplication1+MvcApplication+

I just fixed the same problem just by copy pasting and recompiling solution.